# React mvn unit test

Tags: javascript, java, spring, reactjs, maven

I study for React js now, and I am researching about react testing suite.

I am using spring java and React for now.

How can I run with mvn command to run unit test my React code?

Comment: how are you building your react code? Are you using `npm` or `yarn` or are you directly using the react bundle in your some templates?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide grunt test tasks to maven, to run your JS tests: [Using Grunt with Java and Maven to Automate JavaScript Tasks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-grunt-with-java-and-maven-to-automate-javascript-tasks)

Or you can try [Jasmine](https://g00glen00b.be/jasmine-tests-maven/)